# Reference a yml file in Ansible, which contains calls / executions of specific roles

Tags: ansible

I would imagine this must be easy, but after a few hours of searching I'm at a loss.

Say I have the following playbook, as an example, which does work as expected:

```
- name: Finalize the configuration
  hosts: test_hosts
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  vars_files:
    - vault/credentials.yml

  pre_tasks:

    - name: Set a custom variable
      set_fact:
        custom_var: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['my_custom_var'] }}"

  roles:
    ## My custom role 1
    - role: custom_role_1

    ## My custom role 2
    - role: custom_role_2
      vars:
        variable1: '10.0.0.1'
        variable2: 'template1.j2'
        variable3: 'template2.j2'
        variable4:
          - 'value1'
          - 'value2'
          - 'value3'

    ## My custom role 3
    - role: custom_role_3
      vars:
        variable_a: '8.8.8.8'
        variable_b: 'value_X'
        variable_c: 'value_Y'
        variable_d: 'value_Z'
```

My issue is that the calls for "custom_role_2" and "custom_role_3" are quite complex (in reality, they involve a lot more variables than what I'm showing in my example), so I'd like to keep these separate, in a different yml file which I can then include in multiple playbooks. This way, if at any point I need to change any of the declared variables, I can simply edit only that one file, thus the change would be immediately "seen" by all playbooks.

So, ideally, I would need something like this:

1. A separate yml file (let's call it included_role_execution.yml) which contains the calls/executions for the second and third roles:

```
## My custom role 2
- role: custom_role_2
  vars:
    variable1: '10.0.0.1'
    variable2: 'template1.j2'
    variable3: 'template2.j2'
    variable4:
      - 'value1'
      - 'value2'
      - 'value3'

## My custom role 3
 - role: custom_role_3
  vars:
    variable_a: '8.8.8.8'
    variable_b: 'value_X'
    variable_c: 'value_Y'
    variable_d: 'value_Z'
```

2. The final playbook, which would include that file after the first role:

```
- name: Finalize the configuration
  hosts: test_hosts
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  vars_files:
    - vault/credentials.yml

  pre_tasks:

    - name: Set a custom variable
      set_fact:
        custom_var: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['my_custom_var'] }}"

  roles:
    ## My custom role 1
    - role: custom_role_1

    ## This module does not exist, so I'm looking for an alternative
    - include_role_execution:
        file: included_role_execution.yml
```

Modules such as "include_role" or "import_role", are referring to the actual roles being executed, while my requirement is different (I need to reference the file containing the execution of the roles themselves, including a multitude of variables). Is this possible and if not, what would be a good practice alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution using a combination of **include_role** and **include_tasks** that does exactly what I wanted. In case it will help someone else, here it is:

The **included_role_execution.yml** file should contain the following:

```
- name: Include my_custom_role_2
  include_role:
    name: custom_role_2
  vars:
    variable1: '10.0.0.1'
    variable2: 'template1.j2'
    variable3: 'template2.j2'
    variable4:
      - 'value1'
      - 'value2'
      - 'value3'

- name: Include my_custom_role_3
  include_role:
    name: custom_role_3
  vars:
    variable_a: '8.8.8.8'
    variable_b: 'value_X'
    variable_c: 'value_Y'
    variable_d: 'value_Z'
```

And the playbook:

```
- name: Finalize the configuration
  hosts: test_hosts
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  vars_files:
    - vault/credentials.yml

  pre_tasks:

    - name: Set a custom variable
      set_fact:
        custom_var: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['my_custom_var'] }}"

  roles:
    ## My custom role 1
    - role: custom_role_1

  tasks:

    - name: Include role calls
      include_tasks: included_role_execution.yml
```